# URL with file:// protocol not working in HTML email

Tags: html, protocols, html-email, network-protocols

Why does this work when sent in HTML email

```
<a href="http://someaddress.com/Employee_Survey/index.html" target="_blank">
```

but this doesn't work, as the `<a>` tag completely gets removed off the code (when inspected using chrome inspector)?

```
<a href="file://10.10.1.101/Employee_Survey/index.html" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Define `doesnt work`

Comment: @SimonHänisch I am using it for intranet

Comment: @SimonHänisch — The `file:` scheme does support remote files: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-file-scheme-03#appendix-A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file:` scheme URLs are:

- Poorly supported when they include a network address
- Frequently blocked for security reasons when they appear in a document not served over `file:`

Comment: @FaisalAshfaq — Run an HTTP server on the intranet.

Answer (score 0):

File URLs are rarely used in web pages on the public internet, since host specifier can be used to retrieve a file from an external source, although no specific file-retrieval protocol is specified. It may make hacking easier if we allow the files to access.